# how to make multiselect to singleselect in extjs?

Tags: extjs4, multi-select

Take a look at this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html). Here you can see **`multiselect`** field that allows user to select multiple rows by pressing `CTRL` key down.

[image]

I have tried to use the keyUp function to capture the CTRL key, in order to somehow prevent user from selecting more than 1 row. But I am not sure hot to do this with **mulitiselect xtype**.

You might think way would I want a single select instead of multiselect, it is just something I need for my app I am working on. I like the layout of the example and want to keep the structure the same. The ***only thing I want*** to change is from `multi -> single`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config needs to go in your multiselect config. This will set the config for the boundList which is where the multiselect is.

```
listConfig: {
    multiSelect: false
}
```

Comment: this does not work, the panel freezes and displays 'Loading' all the time

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with multiSelect: false. You didn't post any code. I tested this code before I sent a response so I'm certain it works.

Comment: when you press CTRL and select it still selects multiple items

Comment: It works! http://jsfiddle.net/V99tT/2/.  This is coming directly from the example.